# Node JS - How to call a methods inside a "module.export" function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

lets say I have read_first.js:

```
//read_first
module.exports.create = (arg1) => { 
  const method_I_need = (arg2) => {
    console.log("worked")
  };
};
```

In read_second, I would like to open the method called "method_I_need".
As this method is the child of the "create" method I am stucked.

```
//read_second
var test = require(../read_first.js)

test.create("argument").method_I_Need("argument");
//not working
```

Comment: That's a local variable inside the function, you cannot call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method_I_need` is not the child of `create` but a function only available in the scope of the `create` method. If you want to access it, you could return an object with the functions you want.

You could try the following :

```
// read_first
module.exports.create = arg1 => { 
  const methodINeed = arg2 => {
    console.log('worked')
  }

  return { methodINeed }
}
```